# Appending indices efficiently

Tags: python, tuples

I want to add indices to all tuples in a list (by creating a new list?). I will give an example of what I tried. I wish to make the operation faster and I appreciate any suggestions.

Let's assume I am at a certain iteration having

```
L = [(1463270, 0.681), (1432058, 0.678), (537044, 0.677), (252225, 0.677), (1222737, 0.676)]
```

Here L contains 5 tuples, but I am actually working with hundreds of thousands of tuples in one list.

I wish to add indices to every tuple in L getting to

```
L = [(1463270, 0.681, 1), (1432058, 0.678, 2), (537044, 0.677, 3), (252225, 0.677, 4), (1222737, 0.676, 5)]
```

I need the indices in computing final scores and I tried this:

```
iL = []
for i in range(1,top+1):    ## top = 5 in my example
    iL.append(L[i-1] + (i,))
```

But I really wish to avoid using such a loop when top = 500,000 and having 3,000,000 iterations. Is there a method to resolve my question using map perhaps?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's almost certainly faster to use a [list comprehension](http://treyhunner.com/2015/12/python-list-comprehensions-now-in-color/) than to use `append`.  [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) is a good way to add indices to things in lists; you'll just need to reorder what it gives you to get your desired output:

```
>>> L = [(1463270, 0.681), (1432058, 0.678), (537044, 0.677),
... (252225, 0.677), (1222737, 0.676)]
>>> L
[(1463270, 0.681),
 (1432058, 0.678),
 (537044, 0.677),
 (252225, 0.677),
 (1222737, 0.676)]

>>> [(x,y,i + 1) for i,(x,y) in enumerate(L)]
[(1463270, 0.681, 1),
 (1432058, 0.678, 2),
 (537044, 0.677, 3),
 (252225, 0.677, 4),
 (1222737, 0.676, 5)]
```

Also, consider: do you need to store this new list with indices?  Just allocating the memory for several hundred thousand tuples can take time.  If you're just using this new list for one thing, you might think about using a [generator expression](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators), which evaluates lazily and doesn't need to allocate memory.

Comment: You can specify a starting point as the second argument to `enumerate`: `[(x,y,i) for i,(x,y) in enumerate(L, 1)]`.

Comment: @chepner Nice!  Hadn't seen that one before : )

Comment: Thank you. Please let me know if there are some ways to make my code more time efficient.

    for id in range(212864, 2138098):
        L_src = ... some function call
        L_trg = ... some function call
        iL_src = [(x,y,i + 1) for i,(x,y) in enumerate(L_src)]
        iL_trg = [(x,y,i + 1) for i,(x,y) in enumerate(L_trg)]
        s1 = sum(y*i for (x,y,i) in filter(lambda l: l[0] < th, iL_src)[:count])
        s2 = sum(y*i for (x,y,i) in filter(lambda l: l[0] < th, iL_trg)[:count])
        print ("%d : %f" % ((id + 1), (s1 + s2)))
Sorry, dont know how to edit the code here

Comment: @Tsuki you could try, e.g., `sum(y * (i + 1) for i,(x,y) in enumerate(L_src[:count]) if x < th)`